# Delete a row in DataDridView when a value of NumericUpDown equal to zero

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, delete-row

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Value = "Hawaiian" Then
            row.Cells(1).Value = Double.Parse(NumericUpDown1.Value)
            row.Cells(2).Value = Double.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value) * price
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Hawaiian", 1, price)
```

> the code I put in NumericUpDown to add the item to DataGridView1 is above

[I want the row to be deleted when Qty or Amount equal to zero, in this case, is the row for Hawaiian be delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bx0b.png)

```
 If NumericUpDown1.Value = 0 Then
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
     End If
```

> I tried this but it only deleted the first row in DataGridView1. ***Please help me if you know the answer, I really appreciate it***. I have been trying to solve this for a week, used so many methods online all not work, I still have no clue.

[Expand: the code I added from the comment, it's not deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJwRv.png)

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Wgg.png)

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something, However you question is a little confusing. I will assume that the scenario you describe would go something like this… the user clicks on a row in the grid… then… the user changes the NUD value to zero, at which point the “selected” row in the grid would be deleted? Is this what you are trying to do? Can you [edit] your question to clarify through an example what you are trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: Is what is confusing… is that in the link to the picture that states… _”I want the row to be deleted when it equal to zero”_ … then state that … _”I tried this but it only deleted the first row in DataGridView1.”_ … ? The picture shows the FIRST row as the “CurrentRow”... so we have to ask, “which” row do you want deleted if not the first row?

Comment: thank you for responding, please ignore my code: DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index), its the first time i use DataGridView. I want when any NumericUpDown widget value equals zero, then the relative row is deleted instead of leaving a zero on that row. Thanks.

Comment: Well, given the picture you show with the UI… it appears each NUD is associated with a particular pizza. So, in that case, since the “Hawaiian” NUD was set to zero, then your code will have to loop through all the all rows in the grid until it finds the row where the “Item” is “Hawaiian”… then you will know “which” row to delete. Technically your code will not know “which” row any pizza is in… so you will have to search for it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I tried to locate where the particular pizza is then when it equal zero then delete that row but failed. what makes me really confuse is only the code: DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt work for deleted a row, do you have any idea which code works for deleted a particular row. Anyway, I need so some searching for it. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this far more complicated than it has to be. To simplify things, I suggest you create a method that takes three (3) parameters; a `string` pizza name, a `decimal` quantity and a `decimal` price.

Inside this method, the first step is to check to see if quantity is zero. If it is zero, then loop through all the rows in the grid until we find the pizza name. If the pizza name is NOT found then we can return as the row is not there to begin with. If the row IS found, then we will delete that row.

If the quantity is NOT zero, then we will loop through all the rows in the grid until we find the pizza name. If the pizza name is NOT found, then we know we want to “add” the row to the grid. If the pizza name IS found, then update the quantity and amount cells.

This method may look something like…

```
Private Sub AddOrRemovePizzaInGrid(targetPizza As String, quantity As Decimal, price As Decimal)
  If quantity = 0 Then
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
      If row.Cells("Item").Value IsNot Nothing Then
        If row.Cells("Item").Value.ToString().Equals(targetPizza) Then
          DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
          Return
        End If
      End If
    Next
    Return
  End If
  ' quantity is not zero
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
      If row.Cells("Item").Value IsNot Nothing Then
        If row.Cells("Item").Value.ToString().Equals(targetPizza) Then
          row.Cells("Qty").Value = quantity
          row.Cells("Amount").Value = quantity * price
          Return
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next
  ' if we get here - the target pizza was not found so add as new row
  DataGridView1.Rows.Add(targetPizza, quantity, quantity * price)
End Sub
```

In addition, since there are numerous NUD (`NumericUpDown`) controls on the form and each NUD is tied to a specific pizza, then instead of having a `ValueChanged` event for “each” NUD, I suggest you create ONE (1) `ValueChanged` event and have “each” NUD subscribe to this same event. When the event fires, we will check to see “which” NUD is changing its value, then simply call the above method with the proper info. This should reduce the number of events you have to manage down to one `ValueChanged` event for all the NUDs.

To make the code more readable I suggest you give each NUD a more logical name like `NUD_Pepperoni`, `NUD_Hawaiian` etc… as we will use the NUDs `Name` property to identify “which” NUDs value has changed. This event that uses the above method may look something like…

```
Private Sub NUD_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NUD_Pepperoni.ValueChanged, NUD_Hawaiian.ValueChanged, NUD_Americano.ValueChanged
  Dim target_NUD As NumericUpDown = CType(sender, NumericUpDown)
  Select Case target_NUD.Name
    Case "NUD_Pepperoni"
      AddOrRemovePizzaInGrid("Pepperoni", target_NUD.Value, 8.5D)
    Case "NUD_Hawaiian"
      AddOrRemovePizzaInGrid("Hawaiian", target_NUD.Value, 8.5D)
    Case "NUD_Americano"
      AddOrRemovePizzaInGrid("Americano", target_NUD.Value, 8.5D)
      ' add more pizza types here
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! You are my savior. It works perfectly, learned a lot of stuff from this piece of code!

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot I think that you want to delete the item row from the DataGridView when its quantity set to zero, if so:

You have first to look to the row index in DGV then delete it by doing this:

Make a sub to find the related row & delete it
Call this sub from ValueChanged event of the Numeric object, like this:

```html
 Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
        If NumericUpDown1.Value = 0 Then
            DeleteRowFromDGV("Hawaiian")
        End If
End Sub


Private Sub DeleteRowFromDGV(itemName As String)
        With DataGridView1
            Dim rowToDelete As Short

            For i As Short = 0 To .RowCount - 1
                If .Item(0, i).Value = itemName Then 'suppose that the column index of item name is 0
                    rowToDelete = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            .Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete)
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but seems like it doesn't delete the row when it equals zero, but leave a value 1 on DataGridView1. I don't know how to add pictures to comments. so I updated the more picture and the code to show you what I mean. Thank you

Comment: Sure, because you already adding the row after deleting it in your code in [NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged], 
this line: DataGrudView1.Rows.Add("Hawaiian", 1, price).... this line will add the same row again

see this picture:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8heaRfrvk3tIUqo2LG7N_zZP1Uz4St8/view?usp=sharing

in this picture:
block 1: delete the row of "Hawaiian".
block 2: won't do anything because [If] statement won't find the row ["Hawaiian"] because already has been deleted in the block 1.
block 3: will add the row again.

to try it well : delete the blocks: 2 + 3, or comment it

Comment: Hi, I deleted the block 2 and 3, obviously after I deleted it. It won't add the row in DGV, but only delete the row. And I tried it, only deletes the first row, like many other ways I tried before, any chance you can fix it or I just understand wrong, thank you again.

Comment: Dear clay, each block doing what you code in it, of course the script of Delete will only delete the row, it won’t add the row else you wrote that!
However if you want the same block to delete or add a row you have to use if, else statement: something like that:
If value =0 then DeleteRow… else AddRow….

BTW, to watch what’s happening into the code upon the run time you can use BreakPoint (F9), in this case when the debugger access to this point will stops on this break point so you can watch any variable value, i.e.: RowToDelete then continue with F10 step by step to understand your code.

Comment: I tried what you told me, still couldn't work out. Anyway, there is another guy's code that works really well below, thank you for helping me!